# Error in javascript invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript

Error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

My code in js :

```
var button = document.addEventListener("button");

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    console.log("button was clicked");
 }​;​
```

Answer (score 1):

You used `document.addEventListener("button")`, this would set an event on document, but there is no event named `button`. Also, you did not pass the second parameter to the `addEventListener()` method. You should pass a callback function as the second parameter.

You should use this code instead to log `button was clicked` in the console:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("button was clicked");
});
```

Comment: It's not working it's giving the error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @Adriaj In that case, I'd check to make sure that there is actually an element in your HTML with the ID of `button`.

Comment: @Adiraj Tyler2P is right, please make sure that you've created an element with the ID of button.